# How to format USB created using win32DiskImager.exe

Tags: windows-7, usb

I created an Live debian USB using DiskImager software (win32DiskImager.exe). when I connect this USB , I do not see it under Computer -> Devices With Removable Storage

[image]

But I do see it under Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media and Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers.

[image]

[image]

Any thoughts please on how can I format this USB in Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Disk Management using the command: diskmgmt.msc and you should see a disk listed with multiple partitions.  Verify that the disk's total size matches your USB drive.  You should then be able to assign a drive letter to the disk and format it.  You may need to initialize the disk before being able to manage it.  You also may need to delete the partitions manually and then create a new partition in order to manage it as a single unit.

In most cases Linux Live disks do not get a drive letter automatically whin plugged into a Windows machine unless you used a utility like Linux Live (LiLi) that gives you an option to hide the files on the drive from Windows or not.

[Here's an article on Disk Management in Windows in case you are not familiar with it](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm)

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 and Thanks a lot @Mike Naylor for quick response with perfect solution. Formatting just completed and it is working fine.

Comment: Glad to help.  I've run into this quite often making Linux USB drives with utilities on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can run diskpart:

- select disk Number
- clean

Then you can format it in disk manager up to the full size of the usb drive.